# Is a single Java thread better than multiple threading in my scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

Our company is running a Java application (on a single CPU Windows server) to read data from a TCP/IP socket and check for specific criteria (using regular expressions) and if a match is found, then store the data in a MySQL database. The data is huge and is read at a rate of 800 records/second and about 70% of the records will be matching records, so there is a lot of database writes involved. The program is using a LinkedBlockingQueue to handle the data. The producer class just reads the record and puts it into the queue, and a consumer class removes from the queue and does the processing.

So the question is: will it help if I use multiple consumer threads instead of a single thread? Is threading really helpful in the above scenario (since I am using single CPU)? I am looking for suggestions on how to speed up (without changing hardware).

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The number of cores is only relevant to the number of threads with heavily cpu bound applications. I'd say the vast majority of applications aren't.

Comment: Why 'LinkedBlockingQueue'? Does the data have to be stored in database orderly?

Comment: I think you need to profile your application, before changing it. You have to figureout percentage utilization of IO (network data arrival) and CPU. Batching the data for cpu to process is another possible optimization. But the real question is do you really have a performance problem?

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Try it and see.

This is one of those questions where you argue several points on either side of the argument. But it sounds like you already have most of the infastructure set up. Just create another consumer thread and see if the helps.

But the first question you need to ask yourself:

What is better?
How do you measure better?

Answer those two questions then try it.

Answer (score 1):

Can the single thread keep up with the incoming data?    Can the database keep up with the outgoing data?

In other words, where is the bottleneck?  If you need to go multithreaded then look into the Executor concept in the concurrent utilities (There are plenty to choose from in the Executors helper class), as this will handle all the tedious details with threading that you are not particularly interested in doing yourself.

My personal gut feeling is that the bottleneck is the database.  Here indexing, and RAM helps a lot, but that is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely multi-threading will help, but it is easy to test. Make it a configurable parameter. Find out how many you can do per second with 1 thread, 2 threads, 4 threads, 8 threads, etc.

Answer (score 1):

*First of all:*
It is wise to create your application using the [java 5 concurrent api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

If your application is created around the [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) it is fairly easy to change the number of threads used. For example: you could create a threadpool where the number of threads is specified by configuration. So if ever you want to change the number of  threads, you only have to change some properties.

*About your question:*
 - **About the reading of your socket:** as far as i know, it is not usefull (if possible at all) to have two threads read data from one socket. Just use one thread that reads the socket, but make the actions in that thread as few as possible (for example read socket - put data in queue -read socket - etc).
 
 - **About the consuming of the queue:** It is wise to construct this part as pointed out above, that way it is easy to change number of consuming threads.
 - **Note:** you cannot really predict what is better, there might be another part that is the bottleneck, etcetera. Only monitor / profiling gives you a real view of your situation. But if your application is constructed as above, it is really easy to test with different number of threads.

*So in short:*
 - **Producer part**: one thread that only reads from socket and puts in queue
 - **Consumer part**: created around the ExecutorService so it is easy to adapt the number of consuming threads
Then use profiling do define the bottlenecks, and use A-B testing to define the optimal numbers of consuming threads for your system

Answer (score 0):

As an update on my earlier question:

We did run some comparison tests between single consumer thread and multiple threads (adding 5, 10, 15 and so on) and monitoring the que size of yet-to-be processed records. The difference was minimal and what more.. the que size was getting slightly bigger after the number of threads was crossing 25 (as compared to running 5 threads). Leads me to the conclusion that the overhead of maintaining the threads was more than the processing benefits got. Maybe this could be particular to our scenario but just mentioning my observations.

And of course (as pointed out by others) the bottleneck is the database. That was handled by using the multiple-insert statement in mySQL instead of single inserts. If we did not have that to start with, we could not have handled this load.

End result: I am still not convinced on how multi-threading will give benefit on processing time. Maybe it has other benefits... but I am looking only from a processing-time factor. If any of you have experience to the contrary, do let us hear about it.

And again thanks for all your input.

Comment: Oops.. this posting is from Abdullah but got in thro' a different id.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario where a) the processing is minimal b) there is only one CPU c) data goes straight into the database, it is not very likely that adding more threads will help.  In other words, the front and the backend threads are I/O bound, with minimal processing int the middle. That's why you don't see much improvement.

What you can do is to try to have three stages: 1st is a single thread pulling data from the socket. 2nd is the thread pool that does processing. 3rd is a single threads that serves the DB output. This may produce better CPU utilization if the input rate varies, at the expense of temporarily growth of the output queue. If not, the throughput will be limited by how fast you can write to the database, no matter how many threads you have, and then you can get away with just a single read-process-write thread.